# play framework 2.1.1 get/set tags

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I trying to use custom template tags  but i cant make it work  :(
I'm using  this link as reference  [tags doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTemplateUseCases)

What i trying to achieve is to set some value (string) in one view and get it in another view

In the early   version   1.2.4 look like you can use getter    and setter  this way...

```
Use #{get} and #{set} tags to share variables between the template and the decorator.
```

How  can i get an set parameters in the view ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no get/set tags in Play 2. Every template is compiled to a function and the only way to pass a value from one template to another is by using parameters (= function arguments).

For instance, you can have a block.scala.html template where you define a `title` parameter :

```
@(title: String)
<div>
  <h2>@title</h2>
  ...
</div>
```

And you can just use it form another template using :

```
...
@block("My Title")
....
```